# Google API client is really slow when building the drive v2 API

Tags: google-drive-api

The construction of the drive API service takes a very long time (10+ seconds).  I tried pickling the service and reloading it, but no joy.  Does anybody know how to get this thing to locally cache itself?

```
debug("Building Google Drive service")
from apiclient.discovery import build
self._service = build('drive', 'v2', http = http)

debug("Initialisation complete")
```

Comment: I fixed up your title (missed a space) and got onto the question body, but I don't know what to make of "pickling". Is this a spelling mistake? Jargon maybe? Or are you really trying out [food preservation methods](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=pickling) on the Google Drive API?

Comment: "Pickling" is a python expression.  It involves using the 'pickle' module to essentially 'pickle' an object into a storable data node that can be used to reconstruct the object at a later date.  It is often quicker than initialising objects from scratch, especially for objects that require initialisation through some sort of network data exchange (SOAP or ajax).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn on caching at the http level:

```
http = httplib2.Http(cache=".cache")
```

And please see: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/efficient_use_of_discovery_based_apis

Comment: Excellent read, thank you!  I have implemented the build_from_document() model, with the HTTP request now being cached in a file.

Comment: It seems that the link is no longer active; what does the build_from_document() model do exactly?

Comment: See https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/performance.html